# Problemas al concatenar un nombre de una tabla con un punto

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Este es mi modelo donde quiero hacer la conexión con la tabla. El problema que tengo, es que en la base de datos el nombre de la tabla lleva un punto y a la hora de quererlo hacer, me tira error y no se como podría concatenarlo de alguna forma, 
por que al dejarlo así me da problemas:

```
protected 

$table="`edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact`";

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class importar extends Model
{
  protected $table="`edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact`";


    protected  $fillable  = [
        'PROVEEDOR','DESC_ENLACE','NO_FACTURA','ID_ENLACE','VALOR_PAGO','PERIODO','FECHA_FACTURA','FECHA_INGRESO','MONEDA','TC_FACTURA',
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Este es el error que me tira:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '`edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact`' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `` edavid`.`fcm_enl_ter_fact ``

Answer (score 2):

Al final no sabemos cómo se llamada cada cosa y creo que ahí está el meollo del asunto. La clave de la respuesta me la ha dado [este comentario tuyo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326486/problemas-al-concatenar-un-nombre-de-una-tabla-con-un-punto#comment592464_326497), que no permite entender exactamente **cómo se llama cada cosa**.

Veamos varias posibilidades:

- Si el esquema se llama `david` y la tabla se llama `fcm_enl_ter_fact`, simplemente tienes que escribir el nombre de la tabla así:

  ```
  protected $table="`david`.`fcm_enl_ter_fact`";
  ```
- Si el esquema se llama `edavid` y la tabla se llama `fcm_enl_ter_fact`, simplemente tienes que escribir el nombre de la tabla así:

  ```
  protected $table="`edavid`.`fcm_enl_ter_fact`";
  ```
- Si el esquema se llama `david` y la tabla se llama `edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact` (**no recomendado**), simplemente tienes que escribir el nombre de la tabla así:

  ```
  protected $table="`david`.`edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact`";
  ```
- Si el esquema se llama `edavid` y la tabla se llama `edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact` (**no recomendado**), entonces tienes que declarar la variable así:

  ```
  protected $table="`edavid`.`edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact`";
  ```
- Si el esquema NO se llama de ninguna de esas maneras ni la tabla no se llama de ninguna de esas maneras, entonces **dinos por favor cómo se llama cada cosa**.

El [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) es claro al explicar lo que debemos hacer para usar los backticks:

> If any components of a multiple-part name require quoting, quote them
>   individually rather than quoting the name as a whole. For example,
>   write
>
> ```
>     `my-table`.`my-column`
> ```
>
> not
>
> ```
>     `my-table.my-column`.
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Si algún componente de un nombre de varias partes requiere comillas,
>   cítelas individualmente en lugar de citar el nombre como un todo. Por
>   ejemplo, escriba
>
> ```
>     `my-table`.`my-column`
> ```
>
> no
>
> ```
>     `my-table.my-column`.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Amigo el problema que tienes es por no usar buenas practicas, en esta caso creaste una tabla con un punto y el motor de ejecutar SQL de Laravel te esta dando el error de

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into edavid`.`fcm_enl_ter_fact

Que básicamente te esta diciendo que la tabla no se encuentra. La solución sera que crees una tabla ejemplo: 'edavid_fcm_factura'. Y el error que te da sucede porque el esta pensando que fcm_enl_ter_fact es un campo dentro de la tabla edavid.

[Aquí te puede ayudar y entender como establecer los nombre de las tablas URL.](http://mysql.conclase.net/curso/?cap=nombres)

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si la tabla forma parte de una base de datos que ya existe y no puede modificar?

Comment: Ese es mi problema por que la tabla ya existe no es algo que yo pueda modificar por eso estoy viendo si hay alguna solucion en este caso

Comment: Abría que buscar una forma porque así tenga un . o , te darán esos error. En el caso que ya esa tabla estaba creada en un sistema anterior o en el mismo sistema o en una versión antigua de php. Fíjate como el hace referencia a esa tabla tal vez te sirva de ayuda..
Base de datos -> Cualquier carácter permitido en un nombre de directorio, excepto '/', '\' o '.'
Tabla -> Cualquier carácter permitido para un nombre de fichero, excepto '/', '\' o '.'

Comment: La tabla ya existe en la base de datos es un sistemita que estoy implementando pero tengo ese problema con la tabla intente de esta forma protected $table='edavid'.'fcm_enl_ter_fact'; pero igual me sigue con el error

Comment: Si esta implementando un sistema corrija el error a tiempo. Que la solución seria volver a crear la tabla en sus migraciones de Laravel con '_' en vez de punto. y ejecutar el comando de "php artisan migrate".

Comment: Como bien dices, es una mala práctica crear nombres de tablas o columnas con puntos. Pero si se usa backticks para nombrarlas el manejador las reconocería. Lo raro aquí es que, a pesar de estarla pasando entre `backticks`, como se ve en la variable `$table`, no sé si Laravel o quien no lo está reconociendo así, porque en el mensaje de error está reconociendo las cosas así: `[backtick]edavid[backtick].[backtick]fcm_enl_ter_fact[backtick]`  O, quizá el error provenga de otro sitio y no del código que se muestra en la pregunta ¿?

Comment: ¿La tabla se llama asi? O estas llamando a una BD diferente?

Comment: La tabla se llama asi el hecho es que la tabla se llama de esa forma pero la conexion a la base ingreso con el esquema que seria david y el nombre de la tabla por que aqui a cada quien le dan su usuario y para acceder ala tabla siempre se ingresa de esta forma su usuario y el nombre de la tabla  edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact